# good way to filter items from writable store to display in svelte?

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-store

Is there a better way to do this?

```
<script>
    import recipeStore from '../../recipeStore';
    export let id;  /* I got this id from the url param */
</script>

<div>
    {#each $recipeStore as recipe }
        {#if recipe.id == id}
        <p>{recipe.name}</p>
        {/if}
    {/each}    
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your store-data inside the script tag:

```
<script>
  import {counts} from "./store.js"
  let id=0;
  let mycounts
  const filt=(value)=>{
    mycounts=$counts.filter(count => count.id == id);
    console.log("mycounts: ",mycounts)
  }
  $: filt(id)
</script>
```

You can use `$:` to observe the change in a variable. In my example when `id` changes the `filt(id)` function is called.

Here is REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/77f92f3d3ca149dfa5475035cbbffeb5?version=3.29.0

Comment: This won't work for me, I need to filter thru the store-data without the user invoking a function, I would like to trigger this filtering function without the user interactivity, any ideas? Like I need to grab the item from the array in the store-data on page load to display the correct item right away on page load. any ideas?

Comment: It was just an example of filtering and it’ll work same way if you change id from a top level component or after the component is created (`onMount`). Here is a new REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/77f92f3d3ca149dfa5475035cbbffeb5?version=3.29.0

Comment: Thanks for responding, but you see, in your example, I tried to display the value of text from the selected id, but it didn't work (from you C.svelte file, I updated the last line to try to output the value of the text property of id:2, but the output is undefined..
<script>
  import {counts} from "./store.js"
 import {onMount} from "svelte"
  export let id;
 onMount(()=>{ 
  id=2
 })
  let mycounts
  const filt=(value)=>{
    mycounts=$counts.filter(count => count.id == id);
    console.log("mycounts: ",mycounts)
  }
  $: filt(id)
</script>
<h1>id:{id} {mycounts.text}</h1>

Comment: Filter returns an array, so you need to access it’s properties with `[]` like `mycounts[0].text` You also have to check if filter returns an empty array ie. id is not found. If returned array is empty, you must initialize it `if(mycounts.length==0) mycounts=[{text:""}]` because you can’t access an empty array with `mycount[0].text` I have updated the REPL.

Comment: And you can also update plain `text` variable after filtering like `text = mycounts.length==0 ? "" : mycounts[0].text` or use plain object like `myobj = mycounts.length==0 ? {text:””} : mycounts[0]`